# Can multiple tenants be created under single Microsoft Entra ID P1/P2 plan?

Tags: azure, microsoft-entra-id

Until Azure AD was reorganized into Microsoft Entra Id I could create multiple Azure AD tenants under my Azure account without a problem. Now that things have pretty radically changed I'm wondering if buying the Microsoft Entra ID P1/P2 plan will grant me such functionality?

Comment: Maybe this question wasn't that well formulated. It is theoretically possible to create multiple tenants under the Microsoft Entra ID Free. Due to growing fraudulent use this functionality was urgently turned off so that even if you have paid subscription the ui won't let you create another tenant. See more here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1419156/how-to-create-a-new-microsoft-entra-id-tenant-on-a?page=1&orderby=Helpful#answers.

Comment: By closing this question do you agree that no other similar 'non-programming' question wasn't answered? You haven't spent even a second of your attention to help. Had MSFT / Azure had a better alternative to communicate I wouldn't ever asked it here.